# How to resize QInputDialog, PyQt

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

I am getting input with this here

```
areaInput = QtGui.QInputDialog.getText(self, "Copy Area", "New Area Name:", 0)
```

However I would like to make the dialog box larger, I've tried things such as

```
QtGui.QInputDialog.resize(400, 400)
```

However it says "the first argument must be a QWidget class" and I'm not quite sure what this means or how to fix it. Thanks.

Answer (score 17):

it is possible by doing this:

```
dlg =  QtGui.QInputDialog(self)                 
dlg.setInputMode( QtGui.QInputDialog.TextInput) 
dlg.setLabelText("URL:")                        
dlg.resize(500,100)                             
ok = dlg.exec_()                                
url = dlg.textValue()
```

Comment: Why is this not the top answer?

Answer (score 4):

That error implies that you're not calling an instance method with an instance.

`QtGui.QInputDialog.getText()` is a static method and doesn't return you a `QWidget` instance, so you can't call `resize()` on it.

If you want to call `resize()`, you need to create your own `QWidget` (or QDialog).

Comment: Ok thanks, so there is no way to resize the little pop up with just  simple one line of code?

Comment: No.  But, it would be an interesting exercise to see if you could get a hold of the dialog through the parent's `findChildren<T>()` method (I'm not sure what the PyQt equivalent might be) and on which you might be able to call resize.  But since `getText()` is a blocking call and you would need to call `resize()` from the GUI thread, it certainly won't be trivial.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. Mainly that the window was too narrow horizontally, making the text edit input field small. I ended up putting lots of whitespace after the text in the label argument. Worked fine for me.